# Encode to base64 keystore file

Tags: android, openssl, keystore

I would like encode my .keystore file for use in Gitlab-ci. So, for encode sur base64, i run this command :

`openssl base64 -A -in myFile.keystore`

And for decode :

`openssl base64 -d <<< $KEY > myFile.keystore`

But if i use my file, i've this error : `Invalid keystore format`

I've compare my initial file with new decode file by running `md5sum oldFile.keystore myFile.keystore`, but files is same :/

Anyone have an idea ?

Thank you community !

Comment: What is the format of `myFile.keystore` ? (PKCS#12, PEM, ...)

Answer (score 13):

I tried the same and also had some issues when using `openssl` to perform the base64 encoding.

I believe this to be caused by the trailing `%` characters that `openssl` includes in the decoded base64 string, using something else to encode the keystore worked for me. For example, you can do

```
cat myKeystore.keystore | base64
```

Comment: Add |  tr -d '\n' to remove the newlines