# Should I add debug.keystore to my Semaphore CI build?

Tags: android, react-native, cicd, semaphore-ci

I'm using [Semaphore CI](https://semaphoreci.com/) and my build breaks because there is no `debug.keystore` file found. Should I upload the file to Semaphore?

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningDebug'.
> Keystore file '/root/my-app/android/app/debug.keystore' not found for signing config 'debug'.
```

Comment: You can decode keystore into base64 and paste from CI envs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54881910/encode-to-base64-keystore-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, keep it in your project in git to build debug builds.